# Install and Log into Virtualmin on Google Cloud Compute

Tags: google, virtualmin

i am attempting to run virtualmin on Google cloud engine.
I have used the install script and the installation appears to be ok, however i cannot access virtualmin on port `<webserveripadress>:10000`.

I setup a domain and pointed it at server using an A record and http scan is working no problem displaying the apache default page.

The hostname has been set to `mydomain.com.au`

An MXToolbox scan shows on ports 22 and 80 are open and port 10000 is not on the list at all.

When i check ufw i can see that tcp port 10000 is enabled, however i simply cannot get this to work. I have reinstalled this half a dozen times with different OS on GCE all to no avail.

Can someone give me a point by point procedure on exactly how i get this working on Google Cloud Compute Ubuntu 16, including setting up the firewall and iptables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually open ports 22, 80, 443 and 10000 when i'm installing Virtualmin on GCP. There are more ports you can open. It's being discussed at [What ports should be opened for Virtualmin in firewall?](https://vpsfix.com/community/server-administration/what-ports-should-be-opened-for-virtualmin-in-firewall/)

But mostly above 4 posts should work.

Source: [Install Virtualmin on Google Cloud](https://vpsfix.com/7865/install-virtualmin-gcp-vm-instance-lemp-stack/)

Answer (score 1):

I am now of the opinion that the firewall issue is with Google cloud itself and not the ubuntu server.

I have checked all the ports on the webserver itself:
1.hosts and hostname are set to 
2. port 10000 is open and listening 
3. tcp:10000 is open and listening
4. i have added A records at my domain registrar to point at server ip address (which is same as hostname

I ran an mxtoolbox tcp scan on :10000 and it returned a filtered result.

Can someone confirm that i also need to allow access to :10000 from google cloud console too? (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine )

Comment: did u solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. However the solution was pretty simple.

First make sure that your server is working by running your external ip address in browser with http (not https/ssl).

Then, goto your DNS management provider (i use cloudflare, you can use your domain registrars panel if you want) and add "`A`" record to your external ip with either your domain name or any subdomain if its temporary.

Also, I needed to add firewall entry to google cloud compute instance, the settings are as in the image:

[image]

I hope it helps.